# Passing resend_envelope=true to putEvelopeRecipients return success but not resend

Tags: docusignapi

In Postman [putEnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/) call returns success AND resends the envelope.

When I do the same thing in my C# program I get the identical success text but the envelope is not resent.

I realize my c# code should be presumed guilty, but I'm confused because of the successful response (below).

```
PUT https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<act>/envelopes/<env>/recipients/resend_envelope=true
```

With a body from a GET /recipients call.

Successful result:

```
{
  "recipientUpdateResults": [
    {
      "recipientId": "1",
      "errorDetails": {
        "errorCode": "SUCCESS",
        "message": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "recipientId": "2",
      "errorDetails": {
        "errorCode": "SUCCESS",
        "message": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The envelope is in a sent status.

Comment: I have updated my answer with information regarding the routing order. Let me know if it addressed your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The recipient will only receive the email

- If the envelope status is **Sent**
- The Envelope has reached the recipients Routing order

If the envelope is in a **Created** status then the [PutRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/) call will  succeed, but no email will be sent.